# Accessing a variable from another file (Cypress, JS) results with duplicate test runs

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to access a const variable from another file. Here is the structure:

I have **welcome.spec.js** and here I've declared a const variable as below and exported it. I'm using the value for this spec.

```
context('Welcome', () => {
  // Generating a random userCount value for further verifications.
  const userCount = (Math.round(Math.random()*10))
  module.exports = {userCount}
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.clearCookies()
  })
```

I also have **payments.spec.js** where I need to use exactly the same value.

```
context('Payment', () => {
    const {userCount} = require ('../welcome/welcome.spec')
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('/')
      cy.clearCookies()
    })
```

In several cases, I need to make some assertions depending on that randomly generated value. This structure works but not as I expected. Here is the result:

[image]

Under **Payments**, as you can see, it imports all my tests from **Welcome** as well. I have duplicate tests + randomly generated values are different between those 2 **Welcome** tests.

**What I tried:**

- Moved const declaration out of `context`.
- Tried to create a custom command (../support/commands) but I got errors like **userCount is not a function** or **userCount is not defined**. Also, I tried to use index.js as well under Cypress' support folder.

How can I access that const variable from another file without duplicating my tests and with using the same value? How should I proceed? Is the way that I did the declaration and export wrong?

Note: According to the value ==> const userCount, on Welcome screen user enters this value and on **Payments** input fields are displayed according to that value. (3 users ==> 3 user info fields, etc.)

Thanks in advance!
Regards.

Comment: I'm trying something using **fixtures**. I'll post it if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Export the const outside the context. This is how you can access it in the other file when you import it (ES6).

**welcome.spec.js**

```
const userCount = (Math.round(Math.random()*10))
context('Welcome', () => {
  // Generating a random userCount value for further verifications.
  module.exports = {userCount}
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.clearCookies()
  })
```

---

**payments.spec.js**

```
  import {userCount} from "../welcome/welcome.spec";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the variables into a fixture file:
In **Welcome.spec.js**

```js
// Generating a random userCount value for further verifications.
const userCount = (Math.round(Math.random() * 10))
context('setting test variables', () => {
  it('Setting up test context', () => {
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/test.json', {
      "usercount": userCount
    })
  })
})
```

Then add your other code in there:

```js
context('Welcome', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.clearCookies()
      })
```

In **payments.spec.js**, you can then do this:

```js
context('Payment', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        cy.fixture('test.json').then(data => {
          cy.log(data.usercount)
          // you can access your variable in the data object
        })
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.clearCookies()
      })
```

The fixture file can be used in any spec file once it is loaded.

This issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70004497/keep-dynamic-variables-between-tests-in-cypress) explains how to keep dynamic variables between tests

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72517845/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).